# GetDataTable equivalent for Sharepoint Online powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, splist-getdatatable

I'm in the process of migrating our intranet to SharePoint Online. One of the pieces that I need to tackle is to update all my automation powershell scripts. I have a number of scripts that use the method GetDataTable() on Sharepoint list items. I know that method isn't available in any of the Sharepoint online PowerShell modules (Sharepoint Online, SharepointPNP, or CSOM), but before I have to throw out all my scripts and start again, I thought it would be worth an ask to see if there's any work-around already extant.

In my research, I've found that I can get a Dictionary object using Get-PnPLIstItem and then the FieldValues property. If there was a way to convert that into a DataTable object, that would work perfectly. I need to be able to perform measure-object on the values and also to add the results to the output of an Invoke-SQLcmd.

Comment: How about pasting a working snippet that you would like updated?

Comment: @MichaelColbs There's not too much to paste really. Here's an example where i'm pulling some schedule data 
$schedList = $web.lists["Schedule"].GetITems($schedQry);
$sched = $schedList.GetDataTable()
I know I can iterate through a list item collection and collate the data I need, I'm mainly wondering if anyone has already done the work and rolled their own version of GetDataTable() that I can just drop into my existing scripts without reworking them.